# how do i translate newButton.Click += delegate { window.IsOpen = false; }; in vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net

how do i translate

```
newButton.Click += delegate { window.IsOpen = false; };
```

in vb.net

Comment: http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

Comment: It's really cool, I haven't found any bug so far.

Comment: Yeah not sure how it works - maybe it compiles the language to IL then back again to the target language. Who knows, but iz cool.

Comment: @RPM1984 It would be cooler if it worked for the code in this question. Which it doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another one (with VS 2010)

```
AddHandler newButton.Click, 
    Sub(s As Object, e As EventArgs)
        window.IsOpen = false
    End Sub

following should also work:

AddHandler newButton.Click, 
    Sub()
        window.IsOpen = false
    End Sub
```

**EDIT**: For VS 2008, multi-statement anonymous methods are not possible, so it would be something like

```
AddHandler newButton.Click, _
        Function(s As Object, e As EventArgs) window.IsOpen = false
```

Comment: The VS2008 version doesn't work, it needs to return a value since it is a Function.  It is doing a boolean comparison now instead of assigning the IsOpen property.  Still +1 because the highly upvoted answer is so wrong.

Comment: @Hanks, thanks for pointing out the mistake - but then will there be any alternate syntax? Looks as if its just not possible with VS 2008.

Answer (score 6):

How about

```
newButton.Click += Function() Do
    window.IsOpen = False
End Function
```

This is very helpfull

[Convert C# to VB.NET](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/)

Comment: Are you sure this is valid? VinayC's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448323/how-do-i-translate-newbutton-click-delegate-window-isopen-false-in-vb/4448368#4448368) looks better. I haven't actually tried your code in a compiler but I think it should be `AddHandler` not `+=`, I don't think it can be a `Function` as event handlers are void (have no return value), and the `Do` just looks completely wrong.

Comment: -1 This is **wrong**. Seriously, please **delete** this answer. The online converters all get this wrong. The code does not compile. @Drive-by upvoters who do not know any VB: please do not upvote this answer.