# Delegate Error when converting C# to VBNET

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, vb.net

I have this code in c#

```
void Backup()
{
    string constr = "server=localhost;user=root;pwd=qwerty;database=test;";
    string file = "C:\\MyDumpFile.sql";
    MySqlBackup mb = new MySqlBackup(constr);
    mb.ExportInfo.FileName = file;
    mb.ExportProgressChanged += new MySqlBackup.exportProgressChange(mb_ExportProgressChanged);
    mb.ExportCompleted += new MySqlBackup.exportComplete(mb_ExportCompleted);
    timerRead.Start();
    mb.Export();
}
```

when converted to `VBNet`

```
Private Sub Backup()
    Dim constr As String = "server=localhost;user=root;pwd=qwerty;database=test;"
    Dim file As String = "C:\MyDumpFile.sql"
    Dim mb As New MySqlBackup(constr)
    mb.ExportInfo.FileName = file
    mb.ExportProgressChanged = mb.ExportProgressChanged + New MySqlBackup.exportProgressChange(mb_ExportProgressChanged)
    mb.ExportCompleted = mb.ExportCompleted + New MySqlBackup.exportComplete(mb_ExportCompleted)
    timerRead.Start()
    mb.Export()
End Sub
```

I always get this error

> 'exportProgressChange' is a type in
>   'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlBackup' and cannot be used as an
>   expression.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Duplicates duplicates duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7636382/how-can-i-use-the-following-events-delgates-written-in-c-in-vb-net and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9728926/how-to-convert-this-line-from-c-sharp-to-vb-net-windows-phone-7 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448323/how-do-i-translate-newbutton-click-delegate-window-isopen-false-in-vb

Comment: Hi Derek Floss, I'm one of the author of MySqlBackup.NET. Currently, there is no examples of VB.NET available at the main documentation of this project. Therefore, you welcome to contribute documentations specially for VB.NET at here: http://mysqlbackupnet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Code%20Examples%20in%20VB.NET  This will serve as reference for future programmers of VB.NET. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Private Sub Backup()
Dim constr As String = "server=localhost;user=root;pwd=qwerty;database=test;"
Dim file As String = "C:\MyDumpFile.sql"
Dim mb As New MySqlBackup(constr)
mb.ExportInfo.FileName = file
AddHandler mb.ExportProgressChanged, New MySqlBackup.exportProgressChange(AddressOf mb_ExportProgressChanged)
AddHandler mb.ExportCompleted, New MySqlBackup.exportComplete(AddressOf mb_ExportCompleted)
timerRead.Start()
mb.Export()
End Sub
```

Should work, cause in VB .net you cant use += for subcribing to an event, you have to use `AddHandler` and `RemoveHandler`.

Edit: Tried it, so it compiled fine.